# ASP.NET and C# Page instance and ArrayList variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So venturing in to Web applications from Windows applications and still trying to appreciate some fundamentals. The requirement is basically to have a text box, a button and a label. When clicking the button, the text box displays a pseudo-randomly generated number between 1 and 100. The label will track these numbers as comma-separated values, whilst the text box will be updated with the *latest* generated number each time the button is clicked.

The web page viewed in a client browser has two HTML controls and an asp web control:

```
<input type="text" id="txtOne" runat="server"/>
<input type="button" id="btnOne" value="Generate" runat="server" onserverclick="btnOne_OnClick"/>
<asp:Literal ID="lblOne" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

With the supporting C# class on the server:

```
    public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected HtmlInputText txtOne = new HtmlInputText();
    protected HtmlInputButton btnOne = new HtmlInputButton();
    protected int randomNum;
    Random r = new Random();
    protected System.Collections.ArrayList numbers = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    protected string text;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnOne_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        randomNum = r.Next(1, 100);
        txtOne.Value = randomNum.ToString();
        updateLabel(randomNum.ToString());
    }

    protected void updateLabel(string value)
    {
        numbers.Add(value);
        foreach (string number in numbers)
        {
            text += number + ',';
        }

        //Remove the end ','
        lblOne.Text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
    }
```

When the button is clicked however, only the latest number generated is output to the label. I had presumed that the ArrayList would continue to store the previous values and the iterator loop would retrieve all these in to the text variable.

When the Page object is sent back to the client, does the equivalent of a new instance of Page get sent? This appears to be the case, and if so, what approach is used to solve this?

I suppose I could use the value of the label and increment this with the new value each time (in place of the ArrayList), but I would like to solve it using the ArrayList logic or understand the reason why this isn't correct.

---

TEMPORARY EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace myProj
{
    public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected TextBox txtOne = new TextBox();
        protected Button btnOne = new Button();
        protected int randomNum;
        Random r = new Random();
        protected List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
        protected string text;

        protected void btnOne_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //txtOne.Text = randomNum.ToString();
            randomNum = r.Next(1, 100);
            updateLabel(randomNum.ToString());
        }

        protected void updateLabel(string value)
        {
            if (Session["numbers"] != null)
            {
                numbers = (List<string>)Session["numbers"];
            }

            numbers.Add(value);
            Session["numbers"] = numbers;

            foreach (string number in numbers)
            {
                text += number + ',';
            }

            //Remove the end ','
            lblOne.Text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `<input type="text">` and `<input type="button">`, use `<Asp:TextBox>` and `<Asp:Button>`. Fields (e.g. `numbers` in your example) do not persist between requests, you get a new instance with every request. To persist value you need to use session variabes, e.g. `Session["Numbers"]`.

Comment: RE controls; I did originally. I switched to HTML controls for another test and hadn't switched them back; I ought to do so. I don't think that this will influence the aforementioned problem however?

Comment: arraylist? vs 2010?  Dafuq.

Comment: @Will: the polite way to say that is, "don't use `ArrayList`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `List<string>` instead.

Comment: I see; my continuation of Java at work. Thanks @Will for the benevelont comment, I can only admire such an effective approach to knowledge sharing.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry, I felt like I was struck in the head with a shovel and momentarily dazed.  I'm not responsible for my actions whenever someone tells me they're still using arraylists and VS 2010 *shwabang* ... dafuq???

Comment: @Will: No one likes a cliche and I would advise **against** not taking responsibility for your actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever button will be clicked page will refresh all variables will
>   be reinitialized so arraylist will become empty so how it will retain
>   all values. You may need to store this arraylist in Session and than
>   read from session and loop on it.

When button will be clicked you will first read value from session and assign it to numbers and than add new generated number in it and than assign list to session again.

```
Session["numbers"]=numbers;
```

And when reading from session

```
numbers=(ArrayList)Session["numbers"];
```

Change your updatelabel method to given below and everything should work fine

```
protected void updateLabel(string value)
{
    if(Session["numbers"]!=null)
        numbers = (ArrayList)Session["numbers"];
    numbers.Add(value);
    Session["numbers"] = numbers;


    foreach (string number in numbers)
    {
        text += number + ',';
    }

    //Remove the end ','
    lblOne.Text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);

}
```

Comment: If all variables are initialised and the List<> (formerly ArrayList) becomes empty when the page is refreshed (when the button is clicked), how can the assignment 'Session["list"]=numbers' include previous randomly-generated numbers?

Comment: you will first read value from session add new number in it and than store in session again.

Comment: Thanks. But if the Session[] variable is declared inside a method (btnOne_OnClick) how can the method (Page_Load) access the values stored within it? Would it not have to be declared as an ivar? I have tried this without success.

Comment: Session is accessible everywhere.

Comment: I've still not been able to get this to operate. I have been working through your recommendations, but upon clicking the button, the page refreshes without any values in the label. I have edited my original question with a 'TEMPORARY EDIT' with the current code I am using which is unsuccessful.

Comment: I have posted code after testing and it is working fine for me.There is another error that you have defined txtOne and btnOne in aspx file and in .cs file remove from one of files

Comment: Also check that your session is being created successfully or not if not check if it is diabled ?

Comment: The problem was the attribute onserverclick (for an html button) was being used; not OnClick (for an asp button). Now I have changed this, it functions correctly.